# Can we add Lightning component created in app builder to VF page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I know how to create a Lightning app/component from developer console to a VF page.

But is there a way to add a component built via the lightning app builder 
to a VF page ?

many thanks for answers

Comment: Do you mean to add a lightning component to a VF page?

Comment: I'll clear my question
In salesforce we can bulid an Lightning page via the "Lightning App Builder", my question is : can we add the lightning Page we created there into a VF Page ? or we can only add lightning component to a VF page ?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done